# Checking two passwords to see if they are equal

Tags: java

I have a code in JAVA which connects to a database and gets the password for every user in the database.

Here is the code:

```
private void loginButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String password = "";
        password=loginPasswordField.getText();
        String md5hashdatabase = "3f197eedfeaf826ad2af0bac49ded752";            
        try
        {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            md.update(password.getBytes());
            System.out.println(new BigInteger(1, md.digest()).toString(16));
            String md5hashes = new BigInteger(1, md.digest()).toString(16);
            String m = md5hashes;

            String myDriver = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";
            String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://experimentalx.com/exper482_social";
            Class.forName(myDriver);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "admin", "test");

            String query = "SELECT password FROM social_users";

            Statement st = conn.createStatement();

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

            while (rs.next())
            {
                String encryptedPassWord = rs.getString("password");
                System.out.format("%s\n", encryptedPassWord);

                if(m.equals(encryptedPassWord)) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Its exactly the same!");
                }
                else if(!m.equals(encryptedPassWord)) 
                {
                    System.out.println("Its not the same!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("For some reason, this is just not wanting to work!");
                }           
          }
            st.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
            System.err.println(e1.getMessage());
        }   
    }
```

It gets the passwords, and then checks if the string md5hash is the same as one of the md5 hashes recieved from the database(encryptedPassWord).  When it does this, it just says that all of them are not the same, even though the first hash from the database is the same as the string m(md5hashes).

Have i missed out something?  If so can you please guide me in the right path.  Thank you.

Comment: Are you *sure* the strings are the same?  No trailing whitespace?

Comment: else {
                System.out.println("For some reason, this is just not wanting to work!");
            } will never happen. it'll be either true or false.

Comment: m is set just after String md5hashes = new BigInteger(1, md.digest()).toString(16);

Comment: printout m and encrypted password next to eachother. They must not be exact.

Comment: It's very simple to write a for loop that iterates through the Strings and uses charAt to extract characters one at a time.  Compare the characters that way and see which ones don't match.  (Also, of course, compare overall String lengths first, since there's no chance of a match if the Strings are different length.)

Comment: is this the same code that was used to create the original hashes?  password.getBytes() is platform dependant.

Comment: No, i use php code for that, but this code generates the same hashes as ive checked that.  For some reason, the hashes are the same but it doesnt say they are.....

Comment: Terminology please. MD5 is not encryption: it is secure hashing.

Comment: MD5 without salting - pretty bad hashing function that can easily be cracked by a rainbow table I guess

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(m.trim().equals(encryptedPassWord.trim())) {
                System.out.println("Its exactly the same!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Its not the same!");
            }
```

Comment: You don't want to `trim()` password fields (just in case the password has a space that the OP meant to include in the password).

Comment: as @syb0rg said though, you shouldn't rely on this. it is likely that somewhere one of the two strings is having a newline character added to its end, or something similar

Answer (score 0):

```
private static boolean isPasswordCorrect(char[] input)
{
    boolean isCorrect = false;
    try
    {
        // This is where you encrypt your password
        byte[] einput = Encryption.encrypt(String.copyValueOf(input));
        // I'm not sure where you are loading your encrypted password
        isCorrect = new String(einput).equals(new String(passWordToCheckAgainst));
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return isCorrect;
}

char[] input = loginPasswordField.getPassword();
if (isPasswordCorrect(input))
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(controllingFrame, "Success! You typed the right password.");
}
```

Comment: Try that. `Enctryption.encrypt` is just where you encrypt what you got from the password field.

Comment: If that doesn't work it may be an error with your encryption.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution:

The way i securely hashed the password entered was done wrong and now I have fixed it.  Thank you to all of you for your help.

I changed the encryption to work like this:

```
String value2=loginPasswordField.getText(); //The Password Field (I know getText() isnt secure)
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                md.update(value2.getBytes());
                String value3 = new BigInteger(1, md.digest()).toString(16);
                System.out.println("It should work: "+value3);
```